# How to pass values from a table parameter in a Stored Procedure to another Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure called `FooUpsert` that inserts and updates data in various tables.  It takes a number of numeric and string parameters that provide the data.  This procedure is in good shape and I don't want to modify it.

Next, I'm writing another stored procedure that servers as a sort of bulk insert/update.

It is of tantamount importance that the procedure do its work as an atomic transaction.  It would be unacceptable for some data to be inserted/updated and some not.

It seemed to me that the appropriate way of doing this would be to set up a table-valued procedure, say `FooUpsertBulk`.  I began to write this stored procedure with a table parameter that holds data similar to what is passed to `FooUpsert`, the idea being that I can read it one row at a time and invoke `FooUpsert` for the values in each row.  I realize that this may not be the best practice for this, but once again, `FooUpsert` is already written, plus `FooUpsertBulk` will be run at most a few times a day.

The problem is that in `FooUpsertBulk`, I don't know how to iterate the rows and pass the values in each row as parameters to `FooUpsert`.  I do realize that I could change `FooUpsert` to accept a table-values parameter as well, but I don't want to rewrite `FooUpsert`.

Can one of you SQL ninjas out there please show me how to do this?

My SQL server is MS-SQL 2008.

Comment: You are going to be stuck doing this row by agonizing row.....in other words slow. You are going to have to change one of your procedures anyway. As it sounds you would have to add a **cough** cursor **cough** to FooUpsertBulk to go through your nice set based table valued parameter and call the other proc row by row.

Comment: ^^^^Couldn't agree more. You have to update the sproc anyway. Just make the one proc do both things in a set based operation.

Comment: so you would call `FooUpsertBulk` passing in multiple rows of data, only to cycling though them in that proc so call `FooUpsert` per row? If so, how is that any different than the current operation? And is `FooUpsert` currently being called from another proc or from app code?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping various queries into an explicit transaction (i.e. `BEGIN TRAN` ... `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`) makes all of it an atomic operation. You can:

- start the transaction from the app code (assuming that `FooUpsert` is called by app code) and hence have to deal with the commit and rollback there as well. this still leaves lots of small operations, but a single transaction and no code changes needed.
- start the transaction in a proc, calling `FooUpsert` in a loop that is contained in a TRY / CATCH so that you can handle the ROLLBACK if any call to `FooUpsert` fails.
- copy the code from `FooUpsert` into a new `FooUpsertBulk` that accepts a TVP from the app code and handles everything as set-based operations. Adapt each of the queries in `FooUpsertBulk` from handling various input params to getting fields from the TVP table variables once the TVP is joined into the query. Keep `FooUpsert` in place until `FooUpsertBulk` is working.