# SQL Server passing a table-valued parameters row by row

Tags: sql-server

I have a C# program that passes in a data table to a stored procedure that accepts a type of table. I need to pass the row from this stored procedure into a legacy stored procedure that accepts the values in the tables rows - not a table.

I have the class:

```
public class CondemnedPart
{
    public DateTime HarvestDate { get; set; }
    public string HouseTag2 { get; set; }
    public byte Reason { get; set; }
    public byte Product { get; set; }
}
```

and the corresponding table-valued parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE Abattoir.CondemnedPartsList AS TABLE 
(
    [UpLoadDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [HarvestDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Plant] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Housetag2] VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    Reason VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    Product VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
)
```

So, in my mind, I need to loop through the table rows in here, and pass them to the legacy stored procedure. This seems wrong, but I'm not a SQL Server expert.
How would I best accomplish passing the rows from the table-value into the legacy     stored procedure (which I can't change)?

Ultimately, I need the host PC to build a large number of rows, and the SQL Server machine to process them. Row by row calling is too slow, so a table seemed like a good idea. A single call for each C# datatable.

**EDIT**: I am trying to adapt the old stored procedure into a new one called `BULK_INSERT` ala [Show to Pass Values...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375010/how-to-pass-values-from-a-table-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure-to-another-store). But it doesn't seem to be working very well

**EDIT 2**: I am rewriting this as a stored procedure accepting a TVP of the type above. However, I do not know how to insert this into the stored procedure. For example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Abattoir].[Condemn_RecordScan_Bulk]
     @table AS Abattoir.CondemnedPartsList READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY 
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @ResolveCode TINYINT = 0;
        IF ((SELECT Housetag2 FROM @table) = '299999')
        BEGIN
            SET @HouseTag2 = NULL;
            SET @ResolveCode = NULL;
        END
```

throws a warning about my select from `@table` statement

Comment: What is the SP? if the SP only receive one single row, you need to call it once time for each row. Or create a temporal table and then create another SP to do the loop on the server.

Comment: Passing a TVP, but then having to use a cursor to perform `EXEC` statements to feed the procedure row by row data may well perform even worse than having the client application call the stored procedure in a row-by-row fashion, but that's basically what you'd need to do. Using that as a precursor to rewrite the SP logic is a good idea.